# in jmeter variable value is not incrementing correctly in http request

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

in jmeter> bean shell preprocessor i wrote code to increment the date and this date variable i have passed to a http request. But while debugging only first date is fetching .incremented date is not passing to the variable

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 1);
    SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd 
        kk:mm:ss"); //dd/MM/yyyy
    Date now = new Date();
    String strDate = sdfDate.format(cal.getTime());
    vars.put("timer", strDate);
    log.info("DATE" + strDate);
}
```

this 'timer' variable is not incrementing to http request for 'n' request'

Comment: Why you need that loop creating the value ? You can enter the value when loop ends

Comment: I need to pass 10000 dates one after another.so y i created the loop. I didnt understand how to enter value when loop ends?please clarify

Comment: What your loop does? Just keep putting it in same variable, is there more code that uses the date in each iteration?

Comment: my loop is to increment date and assign to a variable each time when date increments.No other code i have written.

Answer (score 0):

Your code always returns **one** future timestamp (100 seconds ahead of current time) and saves it into `${timer}` variable.

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, there are several options:

1. Change  `vars.put("timer", strDate);` line to `vars.put("timer_" + i, strDate);`, this way you will get the following variables:

   ```
   timer_0=current time + 1 second
   timer_1=current time + 2 seconds
   ...
   timer_99=current time + 100 seconds
   ```
2. Remove loop as it is not really required as you are overwriting `${timer}` variable 100 times

---

Also be aware that using Beanshell is not the best scripting option, according to [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) you should avoid scripting where possible. For instance in particular your case you can achieve the same functionality using [__time()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) and [__longSum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__longSum) functions combination. Check out [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) to get familiarized with JMeter Functions concept.

If you have to go for scripting consider using the most performing language which is [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) (you can use it from [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223))